# Django, how to display separate html blocks, which can then be edited in one place

Tags: html, django, template-engine

I need to display the navbar, footer, main, base, title - in separate blocks, which can then be edited in one place, and the changes will occur everywhere

Сan you give me an idea how to do it, I have no idea just

I thought to do it with this function

```
{% extends "..{directory}/{the name of html page}.html" %}
```

But I think this won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django supports reusable HTML files out-of-the-box

Create your `navbar`, `footer`, and other additional files(if any) separately (most often this type of files stored in `includes` directory), and then you can use them to any files you want by doing so...

```html
{% include 'path/to/template.html' %}
```

For further reading check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include)